# log parser for a log file on remote windows machine

Tags: java, remote-access, logparser

I have a log parser2.2 query for parsing log on remote windows machine.
When the query is run, on log parser command prompt; i get successful output. Following is the query :

```
logparser -i:Textline -rtp:-1  -stats:OFF \"SELECT EXTRACT_SUFFIX(text,0,\'(IBM PC)\') AS REPORT_SINCE from \\\\remote_machine\\remote_folder\\XXXXX.log where text like \'%IBM PC%\'\"";
```

The same command if , used in a java program (jsp); it throws the following error:

```
Task Aborted.
```

Following is error trace :

```
Cannot open : Error opening files: Error searching for files in Error = folder \\remote_machine\remote_folder: Access is denied.
```

Any idea as to why this is happening & how to get it fixed ?

Comment: iam using process builder to get the output of the command in jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access denied means that the application is being run from an account that is not permitted to access that remote folder.  If the command is failing within the context of a JSP, that means that the account / identity that is running the web container doesn't have the necessary permissions.

This could be a deliberate security decision.  Letting your web server access remote shares is asking for trouble ... if your website gets "hacked".  It is prudent to run a web container with minimal privileges as a precaution.

This is not a programming problem *per se*.  Rather it is a problem of figuring out why you don't have permission, and how to get permission safely; i.e. without making your entire network more vulnerable to hackers.  Talk to your local (Windows) system administrators.